# Checking for Blank Date field in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, soql

How do I check if a field is Blank in Salesforce using SOQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

SOQL has support for `NULL` values, so you should be able to query as you do with regular SQL. For example:

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE date_field = NULL
```

Notice the use of `= NULL` instead of `IS NULL` as you would find in SQL.

Comment: Just figured out that this comparison also considers a text field to be null if text_field = ' '. Kinda like the String.IsBlank()